# Chrome and IE focus on Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got an iframe on my page, and a menu that the user can select from to see the gallery he wants inside the iframe.

The gallery in the iframe have the abilty to be controled by the keyboard.

My problem is that I want to change the focus to the iframe so the gallery can be control, immediately afther the user choose the gallery.

I tried a few things and every code worked on Firefox without any problem, but with Chrome, and IE nothing really worked, in IE, and Chrome I have to manually press on the iframe to be able to control it.

(I'm pretty new in JavaScript and I'm using jQuery)

This code I toke from another thread for IE problem and its still didn't work (its only workin in Firefox).

```
 $("#LinkTest li a").focusin(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
     $('#iframeBoxID').focus();
    }, 100);

});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might solve your problem, by focusing on the content window instead of the iframe element.

```
$('#iframeBoxID').get(0).contentWindow.focus();
```

Comment: this is working in IE but in chrome still nothing..its wierd.

Comment: You could try focusing on the body in the window instead.
`$('#iframeBoxID').get(0).contentWindow.document.body.focus();`

Comment: $('#iframeBoxID').get(0).contentWindow.document.body.focus(); not workin in Firefox and chrome.

Comment: for some reson the first answer you gave me now work for all 3 of the browsers i dont know why. thank you!